# Who is the small green caterpillar on my head?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

In Super Mario Wonder, who is the small green caterpillar creature that travels with you, sits on your head, and equips badges? Does it have a name?

[image: small green caterpillar]

Comment: Looks like [Colin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_the_Caterpillar) to me. Well, kind of.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The character is **Prince Florian**, ruler of the **Flower Kingdom**, the primary location of the game's worlds.

[image: Prince Florian]

He acts as a narrator and character being able to talk for and with both the player as well as other characters in the game. In addition, he's also enabling Mario and his friends to equip and use **Flower Badges** modifying or completely changing Mario's behavior and abilities, e.g. giving him different jumps, changing his run speed, spawning extra blocks, etc.

Answer (score 6):

It's Prince Florian.
This is shown after 17s in the first cutscene.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't remember his name after I cleared the game

Comment: I like the inclusion of screenshot evidence and information about where it comes from. However, at least in American English, the word "literally" in this context comes across as condescending. I suggest editing it out.

Comment: @Corrodias done, what I meant is that it was an unmissable information, in my opinion